# Cloning root environment with Anaconda

Tags: python, clone, anaconda

Going through one of (very few available) [tutorials on Anaconda](http://davebehnke.com/using-python-anaconda-distribution.html), I tried:

```
$ conda create -n rootclone --clone root
```

This failed:

```
src_prefix: '/home/bir/conda'
dst_prefix: '/home/bir/conda/envs/rootclone'
Packages: 49
Files: 471
An unexpected error has occurred, please consider sending the
following traceback to the conda GitHub issue tracker at:

    https://github.com/conda/conda/issues

Include the output of the command 'conda info' in your report.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bir/conda/bin/conda", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/bir/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 203, in main
    args_func(args, p)
  File "/home/bir/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 208, in args_func
    args.func(args, p)
  File "/home/bir/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/common.py", line 609, in inner
    return func(args, parser)
  File "/home/bir/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 50, in execute
    install.install(args, parser, 'create')
  File "/home/bir/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 170, in install
    clone(args.clone, prefix, json=args.json, quiet=args.quiet)
  File "/home/bir/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 91, in clone
    quiet=quiet)
  File "/home/bir/conda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/misc.py", line 177, in clone_env
    data = s.encode('utf-8')
MemoryError
```

And badly. The environment is created:

```
$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
oracle                   /home/bir/conda/envs/oracle
oracleclone              /home/bir/conda/envs/oracleclone
rootclone                /home/bir/conda/envs/rootclone
root                  *  /home/bir/conda
```

But it's not working at all:

```
$ . activate rootclone
discarding /home/bir/conda/bin from PATH
prepending /home/bir/conda/envs/rootclone/bin to PATH
(rootclone)bir@N2C:~/python$ which python
/usr/bin/python   # Should be in /home/bir/conda/envs/rootclone/bin
```

But is this a true bug, or is `conda create -n --clone` just not designed for cloning the conda root environment?

Comment: A quick search of the GitHub issues shows that there are other people reporting similar things as bugs and not being told "don't do that, dummy", like [#1248](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1248).

Comment: Meanwhile, whether on their issue tracker or on StackOverflow, you'll probably get more/better help if you tell us which platform you're on, which Anaconda version you have, how you installed it, etc.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you would clone root. Root holds the default packages used when creating new env. You can only clone envs that are in envs folder. Notice that root isn't in the envs folder.

Comment: You should be able to clone root just fine. A conda environment doesn't have to be in the envs directory to be an environment.

Comment: I think you are running out of memory because you are attempting to clone root which contains other envs. When the cloned root is created, it then attempts to clone the cloned root. It's recursive and causes the utility to run out of memory.

Comment: Think of it as attempting to copy `/home/bir/conda` to `/home/bir/conda/envs/rootclone`. The utility will try to copy recursively thereby all files under `/home/bir/envs/rootclone` will also get copied under `/home/bir/envs/rootclone/envs/rootclone` And those files will be copied to `/home/bir/envs/rootclone/envs/rootclone/envs/rootclone`. It's an endless recursion.

Answer (score 41):

Use following command to clone default root environment of Anaconda, the root environment is named as base. This worked for me with Anaconda3-5.0.1

```
conda create --name <env_name> --clone base
```

Comment: Worked to create a new env. But I got a msg: The following packages cannot be cloned out of the root environment: -conda-env-2.6.0-1 -conda-4.5.12-py37_0 -conda-build-3.17.6-py37_0.  If someone could provide some context to this message and why these packages are not cloned, that would be helpful for understanding.

Comment: I got `CondaEnvironmentNotFoundError: Could not find environment: base` and instead had to use `conda create --name <env_name> --clone root` when using Anaconda 4

Comment: @user3731622 - [Cloning Conda root environment does not clone conda and condo-build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784372/cloning-conda-root-environment-does-not-clone-conda-and-condo-build?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The `MemoryError` indicates that the conda process ran out of memory. Perhaps you need to allocate more swap memory.

Comment: I think the clone attempts to clone root recursively thereby creating envs/rootclone which get cloned as envs/rootclone/envs/rootclone.

Comment: Cloning worked fine on a non-root env, so I think the problem might be something similar to alvits' suggestion...

Comment: Does anyone know if this is fixed and it's safe to clone the root env?  I did a little searching, but there were a lot of posts related to errors and cloning the root env.

Comment: check my answer, worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947435/973699