# Cloning Conda root environment does not clone conda and condo-build

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm using conda 4.2.9 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.4.

I cloned the root env with the command:

```
conda create -n rootclone --clone root
```

and it gave the following message:

```
The following packages cannot be cloned out of the root environment:
 - conda-4.2.9-py35_0
 - conda-build-2.0.2-py35_0
```

Will this be a problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Conda only works from the root environment. So cloning the conda part is not possible. Even when you have a different environment activated, the command `conda` will be the one from root.

For example, if I activate my Python 3.5 environment (on my Mac):

```
source activate py35
```

And look for `conda`:

```
(py35) macintosh-4:measuring mike$ which conda
/Users/mike/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/conda
```

It looks like it is a in the `py35` environment.

But the file:

```
less /Users/mike/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/conda
#!/Users/mike/anaconda/bin/python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import conda.cli

    sys.exit(conda.cli.main())
/Users/mike/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/conda (END)
```

contains this shebang to the root environment `#!/Users/mike/anaconda/bin/python`.

So, there is no problem with your cloning.

Comment: Hi, I have a question to bother you. When I activate a environment, I installed some packages via ''conda install package''. It truely install packages in my sub-environment...If packages installing use my root conda, shouldn't be installed in my base environmet? Or maybe the reason is that conda can identify which environment should the package be installed in? Thank you!

Comment: You are right. Conda knows about the currently active environment. All actions are towards this environment That is the whole point.