# Install Default Packages into Conda Virtual Environment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

So I have Anaconda 2018.12 which has python 3.7. To work with python 3.5, I created a virtual environment that uses python 3.5. I opened Spyder in this environment only to see that most of the default packages like numpy and scipy aren't installed.

I know I can just install them either through the Anaconda Prompt or the Anaconda Navigator GUI, but is there a way to just have all the packages that already exist in the base environment also be installed into this virtual environment? Thanks.

Comment: This is a common question. Do you want _all_ the packages from the base environment?

Comment: @roganjosh It's not necessary, but would it be a lot of trouble to do that?

Comment: No, but you'll end up dumping loads of libraries into your virtual environment that you probably never use

Comment: Well, I guess I won't do that then, but could you explain how just in case I ever do need to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloning root environment with Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291733/cloning-root-environment-with-anaconda)