# Conda : How to install a python packages from base environment to new environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have anaconda distribution installed on a computer without connection to the internet.

i have created a new environment and activated it
using the following commands:

```
conda install -p c:\python\test_env --offline
```

and then

```
conda activate c:\python\test_env
```

Could you please instruct me how to install into this new environment
the following items,

**including their dependencies,**

**all from (base) environment:**

python

jupyter lab

pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloning root environment with Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291733/cloning-root-environment-with-anaconda)

Answer (score 9):

[Clone](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#cloning-an-environment) it (but first delete `test_env` to start fresh):

```py
conda create --name test_env --clone base
```

This'll carry over all libraries, packages, and their dependencies - without affecting `base`.

Comment: What if I don't want to clone all packages? What if I created new environment and wnt to add only 1 specific package from base? I don't want to recreate my env, because I already install a lot of additional packages from another sources.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Then copy/paste only that package from base and run `conda update --all` to ensure compatibility (or don't, but risks package conflicts)

Comment: I found one more (maybe easier) solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102511/clone-some-packages-from-base-env-to-another-one

Answer (score -1):

Try this command to avoid confusion

conda install -c conda-forge

the above command will install the packages in the system irrespective of the environment.

You can add packages listed in environment.yml file to an existing environment by using the following command

conda env update -n conda-env -f /path/to/environment.yml