# Clone some packages from base env to another one

Tags: python, anaconda, python-packaging

I installed anaconda. So I already have a lot of packages installed.
Now I created new one env (almost empty).
And start to install some specific packages to it.
I have no internet on this machine, so I need to copy wheels or source files to it.

Ok, it works, but Why I need to download and copy some packages like numpy when I already have it in base env?

So my question is - How to install packages to new env if I already have them in base?
--use-locals key or smth else?

---

I found this one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59086858/conda-how-to-install-a-python-packages-from-base-environment-to-new-environmen). But I don't want to copy all of packages! I don't need all of them. I need 10-20 specific of them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: just use `--offline` option:

```
conda activate my_env
conda install numpy --offline
```

Comment: Works, though note this should be identical to copy-pasting, and conda will be unable to resolve version conflicts if there are any as it cannot fetch new packages from online channels (unless you download them ahead of time somehow, which I wouldn't know)